# How to add macros to visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I need to add a macro to a visual studio project so that i could use this macro to set properties of the project.

[image]

e.g. I could replace 192.168.1.50 to a macro naming $(RemoteComputer).

Could I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two options:

1. Make it an environment variable like PATH or APPDATA (My Computer->Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables). Note that you need to restart MSVC or it will not find the new environment variables.
2. If you want the setting only for a single project, then open the `.vcxproj` file and go to `Project/PropertyGroup[Label="Globals"]`. Add a new tag here, e.g. FooBar and it will appear as a $-macro in the studio-settings for that project.

Comment: Macros can also be imported from other project files using `<Import Project="foo.props" />`